# Запятая при уточнении

Tags: запятая

Прочитала в газете: По работе "Паркона" было выявлено с начала 2015 года свыше 1000 нарушений, на сумму свыше 1,5 млрд руб. Правильно ли стоит запятая. Зачем? при уточнении? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это авторское пояснение, факультативный знак, не ошибка, но и не обязательное выделение.

Answer (score 1):

**На мой взляд, запятая обязательна.** Без неё возможно двоякое понимание предложения:

*-- выявлено свыше 1000 нарушений на общую сумму свыше 1,5 млрд руб.;*

*-- выявлено свыше 1000 нарушений,  каждое из которых -- на сумму свыше 1,5 млрд руб.*